# SQL query for a database with two many-to-many relationships in a 'loop'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Firstly apologies for the woolly subject title, its hard to put this one into words.

So…with that in mind I’ve attached a database relationship diagram (see below) which will hopefully explain it much more concisely.

[image]

We have inherited a large database (and therefore have no ability to change/rationalise it, more’s the pity!) which has a troublesome ‘loop’ of 4 tables that have a couple of different many to many relationships within.

I need to be able to get out the Court’s name, full address, and general notes, all of which every court will only have one of, followed by the Contact details which are divided into two groups (general and specific contact points) which could contain one or more listings dependent on the court. I need this to appear in the format below:

**Abergavenny Magistrates' Court**
Abergavenny
NP7 5DL

This court is open for hearings only. Additional Court Notes….

**Contacts**
Switchboard: 01633 64xxxx
Fax: 01633 64xxxx
Service 1: 01633 64xxxx
Service 2: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 1 - Acting Court Manager: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 2 - Acting Office Manager: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 3 - Acting List Officer: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 4 - Justices' Clerk: 01633 64xxxx

I posted on StackOverflow yesterday to find out how to correctly write the SQL query and ASP.NET C# code for one many-to-many relationship. For simplicity’s sake the info I provided was very much paraphrased and basically contained only half of the loop you see above. However I’ve since failed in my attempt to apply the same principles to the full loop.

The SQL query (which works for the first half of the loop, i.e. to provide the court address details and a list of the specific contact points) looks like this:

```
string myQuery = 
"SELECT C.court_id, court_name, court_addr1, court_town_name, court_county_name, " +
"court_country_name, court_addr_pcode, court_addr_dx, court_code, court_note, " +
"court_contacts_name, court_contacts_no, CCT.court_contact_type_desc " +      
"FROM court C " +
"JOIN court_addr CA ON C.court_addr_id = CA.court_addr_id " +
"JOIN court_town CT ON CA.court_town_id = CT.court_town_id " +
"JOIN court_county CC ON CT.court_county_id = CC.court_county_id " +
"JOIN court_country CCO ON CC.court_country_id = CCO.court_country_id " +
"JOIN court_contacts CCON ON C.court_id = CCON.court_id " +
"JOIN court_contact_type CCT ON CCON.court_contact_type_id = CCT.court_contact_type_id " + 
"WHERE C.court_id = '25' " + 
"ORDER BY C.court_id";
```

Whilst the C# looks like this:

```
if (myDataReader.HasRows)
{

    string last_id = string.Empty;

    while (myDataReader.Read())
    {

        string court_id = myDataReader["court_id"].ToString();
        string court_name = myDataReader["court_name"].ToString();
        string court_addr = myDataReader["court_addr1"].ToString();
        string court_town = myDataReader["court_town_name"].ToString();
        string court_county = myDataReader["court_county_name"].ToString();
        string court_country = myDataReader["court_country_name"].ToString();
        string court_pcode = myDataReader["court_addr_pcode"].ToString();
        string court_dx = myDataReader["court_addr_dx"].ToString();
        string court_code = myDataReader["court_code"].ToString();
        string court_note = myDataReader["court_note"].ToString();
        string court_contact_name = myDataReader["court_contacts_name"].ToString();
        string court_contact_desc = myDataReader["court_contact_type_desc"].ToString();
        string court_contact_no = myDataReader["court_contacts_no"].ToString();

        if (last_id != court_id) {

            Response.Write("<strong>" + court_name + "</strong><br>" + court_addr +
                           "<br>" + court_town + "<br>" + court_county + "<br>" + 
                           court_country + "<br>" + court_pcode + "<br><br>" + 
                           court_dx + "<br><p>Court code " + court_code + "</p><p>" + 
                           court_note + "</p>" + court_contact_name + " - " + 
                           court_contact_desc + ": " + court_contact_no + "<br>");

        } else {

            Response.Write("<br>" + court_contact_name + " - " + court_contact_desc + 
                           ": " + court_contact_no + "<br>");

        }

        last_id = court_id;

    }

}
```

Following the same logic in the SQL query I’ve tried to add an additional SELECT parameter of **court_contacts_general_no** and a couple of extra JOIN lines to bring in the **court_contacts_general** table (see below), however, this produces errors along the lines of ‘The correlation name CCG is specified multiple times in a FROM clause’ or just goes completely blank if the 2nd correlation name is removed.

```
"JOIN court_contacts_general CCG ON C.court_id = CCG.court_id " +                                  
"JOIN court_contacts_general CCG ON CCT.court_contact_type_id = CCG.court_contact_type_id " +
```

Whilst in the C# I’ve added a new string for **court_contact_general_no** and tried creating another if/else loop based on writing the response received from this new variable.

Either way, all I’m getting is a big blank page or the SQL related errors above.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all/any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly not elegant (no doubt there's a much better way of writing it!) but I've managed to work out a solution to the problem by writing a second SQL query and opening a second Sqlconnection directly after the first one has closed to tag on the second batch of contacts.

SQL query:

```
string myQuery2 = 
"SELECT C.court_id, court_contacts_name, court_contacts_no, court_contact_type_desc " +
"FROM court C " +
"JOIN court_contacts CCON ON C.court_id = CCON.court_id " +
"JOIN court_contact_type CCT ON CCON.court_contact_type_id = CCT.court_contact_type_id " +
"WHERE C.court_id = '" + court_id_no + "' " +
"ORDER BY C.court_id";
```

C# code:

```
myDataReader.Close();
connection.Close();

SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(myQuery2, connection2);
SqlDataReader myDataReader2;
connection2.Open();

myDataReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

if (myDataReader2.HasRows) {

    string last_id = string.Empty;

    while (myDataReader2.Read()) {

        string court_id = myDataReader2["court_id"].ToString();
        string court_contact_desc = myDataReader2["court_contact_type_desc"].ToString();
        string court_contact_name = myDataReader2["court_contacts_name"].ToString();
        string court_contact_no = myDataReader2["court_contacts_no"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(court_contact_no)) {
            court_contact_no = generic_contact_no;
        }

        if (last_id != court_id) {

            Response.Write(court_contact_name + " - " + court_contact_desc + ": " + court_contact_no + "<br>");

        } else {

            Response.Write(court_contact_name + " - " + court_contact_desc + ": " + court_contact_no + "<br>");

        }

        last_id = court_id;

    }
}
```

As I say, not pretty but the important thing is it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use different table name aliases in order to join the same table more than one time in a single query

```
JOIN court_contacts_general CCG1
JOIN court_contacts_general CCG2.. etc
```

I'd recommend naming the tables something more relevant to what data is being returned though in that case

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but I got a blank screen again. I've managed to work around it now - I'll post the answer below. It's not elegant but it works.